# Alternative to GIF file that I can embed in word

Tags: ms-word, gif, animated-gif

I am currently writing my dissertation and I had an idea to create a gif of my screen (I am studying for a degree in computing).  The GIF is basically an animation of a graph in a piece of software I have written.

Anyway so I have the completed GIF and I have since found out word cannot display the animation, it only shows the first frame...gutted.

So I thought I would just embed the file so I can place it in an appendix and then ask the reader to double click the file and hey presto! they can see the gif.  This doesnt work either I get a htmlfile error.

Is there an alternative to a gif that I could produce and use in word 2013 to achieve the same result?

Comment: Best way is to save it as html and open with Browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Drag and drom `PowerPoint Show(.ppsx in Office 2007)` file in Word. Whenever you double click on that It will go full screen, press esc to exit show.